# How to parse the JSON coming from all the URL's using Python?

Tags: python, regex, json

I have a URL which gives me the below JSON String if I hit them on the browser -

Below is my URL, let's say it is `URL-A`

```
http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
```

And below is my JSON String -

```
{
 "description": "",
 "statistics": {
  "dataCount": 0,
 }
}
```

So like the above `URL-A`, I have around 5 urls, which also gives me the same JSON String back but it might be possible that `dataCount` count is not zero in them.

Now what I am supposed to do is, I need to write a Python script which can scan all the 5 URL's and then parse then JSON String to extract the `dataCount` from it and its count as well. And it should keep on running every few seconds to scan the URL and then parse it.

Below are my URL's

```
URL-A       http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
URL-B       http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
URL-C       http://hostnameC:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
URL-D       http://hostnameD:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
URL-E       http://hostnameE:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
```

And the data I want to see is like this on the console, here dataCount will be actual number

```
hostnameA - dataCount
hostnameB - dataCount
hostnameC - dataCount
hostnameD - dataCount
hostnameE - dataCount
```

Is this possible to do it in Python?

**UPDATE:-**

This is what I have tried -

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json"
response = urllib.urlopen(url);
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```

But how to do the same thing for other 5 URL's and keep on scanning it every 10 seconds and also extract dataCount from it?

Comment: Yup, that's perfectly possible.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself yet? Like look at the `urllib2` and `json` libraries? There is **no need** to use regex here, btw.

Comment: Yup I have tried that but didn't pasted my answer in the question. Just updated my question..

Comment: `data['statistics']['dataCount']` gives you the data count from the dictionary. You don't know about loops yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from time import sleep

def get_data_count(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return 'could not get page'

    try:
        return int(req.json['statistics']['dataCount'])
    except TypeError:
        return 'field not found'
    except ValueError:
        return 'not an integer'

def main():
    urls = [
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameC:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameD:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameE:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json')
    ]

    while True:
        print('')
        for name, url in urls:
            res = get_data_count(url)
            print('{name} - {res}'.format(name=name, res=res))
        sleep(10.)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit:** in response to AKIWEB:

Running Python 2.7.6 with requests 0.13.2 on Window 7 x64:

```
>>> requests.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two').json
{u'key': u'value', u'one': u'two'}

>>> requests.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two').json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    requests.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two').json()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Yes, I am pretty sure.

Comment: You missed braces next to `json` in `req.json` I guess.

Comment: @AKIWEB: actually not; json is a property, not a method, so this runs properly exactly as is.

Comment: Are you sure? For me its not working if I run this as it is, I always get field not found.. But if I replace this `req.json['statistics']['dataCount']` with `req.json()['statistics']['dataCount']` then it starts working..

Comment: Very strange.. Not sure whether this will make any difference or not.. I am running Python 2.7.3 and using CYGWIN.